# How to remove or close unclosed HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string

Supposedly I have a string like this that will go to my HTML:

```
<div>Wakanda Forever</div> <span class="movie">Black Panther</span>
Movies movies movies 
<span class="movie">Spider man...
```

The last span tag isn't closed.

In Regular expression and JavaScript, how can I remove  the unclosed `<span class="movie">` from `<span class="movie">Spider man...` or close it with a `</span>` tag?

Comment: If you assign this to `.innerHTML`, the browser will automatically close it.

Comment: Telling him to use an HTML parser doesn't help when the problem is that the input isn't valid HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a problem that can be solved in the general case with regular expressions. You need a parse tree

Comment: @CherryDT can't read your comment

Comment: It's an esoteric Stack Overflow meme; rarely helpful. It used to be funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using regular expressions to do any sort of HTML manipulation is almost always a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/).

My recommended solution would be to do what the browser does: Parse the string into a DOM (in a similar fuzzy, forgiving way) and then turn that DOM back into HTML.

In a browser environment, this is especially easy because you can let the browser itself do it for you, by writing the bad HTML into `innerHTML` of an element and then reading it back - and the browser will have fixed it for you:

```js
const badHtml = `
<div>Wakanda Forever</div> <span class="movie">Black Panther</span>
Movies movies movies 
<span class="movie">Spider man...
`

const element = document.createElement('i')
element.innerHTML = badHtml
const result = element.innerHTML

console.log(result)
```

In node.js, you could instead use a library like [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/):

```js
import cheerio from 'cheerio'

const badHtml = `
<div>Wakanda Forever</div> <span class="movie">Black Panther</span>
Movies movies movies 
<span class="movie">Spider man...
`

const $ = cheerio.load(badHtml)
const result = $.html()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: If I create this "element" by using 'document.createElement('i')' without adding it to the DOM, what will happen? Do you need to deference "element" since it's the html return from innerHTML that I need. I don't need the element created.

Comment: If I put these code in a function, after the function is exited, the "element" will be dereferenced?

Comment: JavaScript has a garbage collector. Since the element isn't used anywhere afterwards (and also isn't part of some function's closure like in an event listener), it will eventually just be thrown away, there is nothing you need to do about it. (Of course you could try to optimize this a bit by creating the element outside of the function and reusing it every time.)